# any postsharp document for VS2012?

Tags: postsharp

I downloaded and installed Postsharp 4.0 express for V 2012. I can't find any postsharp dlls when I try to add reference. 
 when I use Nuget,  I can't find PostSharp Laos dll.

Answer (score 0):

I recently downloaded the post-sharp extension fow Visual Studio 2012 and worked very well for me.

I looked this tutorial [Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS)

I Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

PostSharp consists of the [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a058d5d3-e654-43f8-a308-c3bdfdd0be4a) that provides UI tools with the IDE, and the [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PostSharp/) that contains the post-compiler and relevant libraries.

When you install PostSharp NuGet package for your project, the required references and *.csproj modifications are provided automatically.

If you already have the VS extension installed, then you can right click on your project in the Solution Explorer and select "Add PostSharp to project".

You can also find more information in the getting started documentation available online: http://doc.postsharp.net/getting-started